# How to import images using command line in 'cameraCalibrator' app?

Tags: image, matlab, camera-calibration, calibration

I would like to import images (from a directory or a MATLAB variable) into 'cameraCalibrator' app using command-line.

I found the below syntax:

```
cameraCalibrator(imageFolder,squareSize)
```

Here is how I tried to use it:

```
cameraCalibrator(desktop,3*mm);
```

But it is yielding some error. How to apply this syntax?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameracalibrator-app.html#burd_hd-4)? Input arguments are also self-explanatory though. Please show exactly how you're using it and the exact wording of the error message that you're receiving.

Comment: @SardarUsama , I read the documentation. only the above syntax is given and not an example to see how to use it. Here is how I tried to use it. *cameraCalibrator(desktop,3*mm);*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two input arguments must be given as follows:

1. I suggest creating a separate dedicated directory for your image files. e.g; if your image files are in a directory named `images` on `Desktop` then give its complete path like this:

   ```
   imageFolder = 'C:/Users/<yourusername>/Desktop/images';        %For WinOS
   ```

   You can just write name of the directory as well if `Desktop` is your current working directory i.e.

   ```
   imageFolder = 'images';
   ```
2. `squareSize` is, [by design](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameracalibrator-app.html#burd_hd-4), to be given in `mm`. So `mm` must not be explicitly specified. For your case, it will be:

   ```
   squareSize = 3;
   ```

   Now run it with:

   ```
   cameraCalibrator(imageFolder, squareSize)
   ```

---

Note that you can also just enter `cameraCalibrator` which lets you choose the images and square size in GUI.

[image: select_images]

After selecting images, the following window appears which also lets you to choose the square size in different units:

[image: square size]